# Setting label text to datagridview cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to set a label to the column1 value (User ID) of the row I select.  So if I select the 5th row, the label text should be the 5th row, column 1 value .  Nothing changes.  What am I missing?

```
private void DGV1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
         {

         foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in DGV1.SelectedRows)
         {
            label4.Text = dgvRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
         }
 }
```

Comment: `There is the RowIndex property for the CurrentCell property for the DataGridView.

datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex`
`Handle the SelectionChanged` event and find the index of the selected row as above.

Comment: try CellClick instead of CellContentClick

Answer (score 0):

@MethodMan, thanks. What I have now works.

```
private void DGV1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            label4.Text = DGV1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        }
```